# How to create semi transparent pattern with python pil?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have found some examples on this [site](https://www.unioviedo.es/compnum/labs/PYTHON/intro_image.html). I would like to create, example 6. Can you help?

Create, as a numpy array, the image of the napkin. The squares have a size of 10×10. You may use the command numpy tile. Save the resulting image to a file.

[image]

Comment: Also, how to make line of like slashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Make grey 2x2 image
TwoByTwo = np.full((2,2), 128, np.uint8)

# Change top-left to black, bottom-right to white
TwoByTwo[0,0] = 0
TwoByTwo[1,1] = 255

# Tile it
tiled = np.tile(TwoByTwo, (5,5))

# Make into PIL Image, rescale in size and save
Image.fromarray(tiled).resize((100,100), Image.NEAREST).save('result.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In a standard grayscale image, black pixels are `0`, gray pixels are `128`, and white ones are `255`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# first create one 20 x 20 tile
a1 = np.zeros((20,20), dtype=int)
a1[10:20,0:10] = a1[0:10,10:20] = 128
a1[10:20,10:20] = 255

# fill the whole 100 x 100 area with the tiles
a = np.tile(a1, (5,5))

# plot and save
plt.imshow(a, 'Greys_r')
plt.savefig('pattern.png')
```

Comment: Can I do this with pillow without figure?

Comment: Yes, using `Image.fromarray(a.astype('uint8'), 'L')`, but you get just the pattern, without the axes.